# Application of Banach-Steinhaus Theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis

Prove: For a subset $A$ of a normed space $X$, the following are equivalent:

- $A$ is bounded
- $x^*(A) \subset \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ is bounded for every $x^* \in X^*$.

I think I have to use a combination of Hahn Banach and Banach Steinhaus theorems to prove this. But I am confused how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is bounded, there is some $M>0$ such that 
$$ \|x\|\leq M $$
for all $x\in A$.  Then for $x^* \in X^*$ we have
$$ |x^*(x)|\leq\|x^*\|\|x\|\leq M\|x^*\|, $$
and therefore $x^*(A)$ is bounded.

To prove the converse, observe that $X$ is isometrically isomorphic to a closed subspace of $X^{**}$.  By assumption, we have
$$ \sup_{x\in A}|x^*(x)|<\infty $$
for all $x^*\in X^*$.  The Banach-Steinhaus theorem then implies that
$$\sup_{x\in A}\|x\|<\infty, $$
and therefore $A$ is bounded.